# python selenium automation instagram

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Im trying to login to my instagram and like pictures on my feed. I'm using selenium to automate the process. The function below will only like the first two pictures. When the home feed is loaded I see 4 "article" elements in the html. I want to loop through the article elements liking each picture but the code only likes the first 2 picture. How can I make it like all the pics.

```
def like_my_feed(self):

        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en")
        time.sleep(2)

        try:    

            articles= driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("article")
            print(len(articles))
            time.sleep(2)

            for article in articles:
               like= article.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@aria-label="Like"]')
               like.click()



        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Comment: Are you sure all the xpaths are the same

Comment: @Noah im not sure

Comment: You need to check , often they change , which would make sense because you said it was only able to like 2, and they’re appears to be nothing wrong with your code. Upvote comment if it helped